# How to speed up my PDAL pipeline script?

Tags: python, classification, point-cloud, pdal

I'm creating an app for point cloud processing. I've made a pdal script with Python and I have some trouble with the cpu usage and processing speed I've made a pipeline for las processing, with some filters for ground classification (smrf, sample,...). Everything works perfectly, but it's very slow on large file (over 5gb). When I check the cpu usage it is always around 20%. Is there a way to use more CPU core for processing these data ?

Here is my PDAL processing script :

```
import pdal
import json
import os
import time


ds_source_lidar = r"D:\ELDA\Technique\TRAITEMENT EP NEIGE\LAS\1400\Snowpark\cloud2e437822524c19f2.las"
ds_shp = r"D:\ELDA\Technique\TRAITEMENT EP NEIGE\LAS\1200\Pitch Vauban 20-02\vauban.shp"
otp = r"D:\ELDA\Technique\TRAITEMENT EP NEIGE\LAS\1400\Snowpark\testtherads12.las"

start_time = time.time()
input = ds_source_lidar
output = otp
convertion = {
"pipeline" : [
    
    {
        "type" : "readers.las",
        "filename" : input
    },
    {
        "type": "filters.sample",
        "cell": "0.08"
    },
    {
        "type" : "filters.smrf",
        "scalar": "1.2",
        "slope": "0.2",
        "threshold": "2",
        "window": "25"
    },

    {
        "type" : "filters.assign",
        "value" : "Classification = 4 WHERE Classification !=2"
    },
    {
        "type" : "filters.range",
        "limits": "Classification[2:2]"
    },
    {
        "type" : "writers.las",
        "filename" : output 
    }

    

    
]

}

pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json.dumps(convertion))
pipeline.execute()

print("Traitement pdal terminé")

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print("Temps écoulé:", elapsed_time, "secondes")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDAL doesn't internally split your data. Some algorithms, especially those like `filters.smrf` require reading ALL of the data to start processing. It is the responsibility of the user to split files up into work units that are desired, with collars as appropriate, to process data.

Utilities like the newly-created PDAL `wrench` command https://github.com/PDAL/wrench/ are starting to do this for you, but nothing is available for automatically doing `filters.smrf` with large files at this time. You will need to split up the data yourself.